# Integration of Python code with existing ASP.NET, C# Application

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to integrate open source ERP with my application which I‘ve been developing in asp.net, c#. I am planning to integrate one module like Purchase Module from Open ERP .The source code for the module has been downloaded which is in Python language, the related DB table structure is also available.

Please suggest me which will be the easy way of integrating open source ERP module source code which is in Python language with my present application which is in asp.net, c#.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In honesty, this isn't going to be clearcut, as you're not just going to be able to plump a Python website alongside an ASP.Net website and have them inter-operate without a bit of effort.

One possible line of research is that you can run Open ERP using IronPython, which is a version of Python that uses .Net instead of a C Runtime. If it's written well, you may be able to then use the objects in OpenERP from your C# code to access the data saved.

What might be more simple, is to have a look around for an open .Net project that provides the functionality you're looking for...

Integrating OpenERP with .Net isn't something that can be solved in a Stack Overflow question, it's something I'd tell my boss I'd want a couple of days to research to see if it's even viable.

Comment: I'm basing my suggestion that OpenERP works on IronPython because of the point at the bottom of this blog post:  http://powerphil.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/how-to-fix-openerp-performance-issues/

Comment: Just an update on this: I came to the conclusion IronPython is unlikely to work, based on this: http://forum.openerp.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=115291 and the lack of any references to it since on the web.